# Create array from existed array

Tags: java, arrays, android-studio

I have an array

```
myArray []={1,4,3,2}.
```

I want to create 4 new array like:

```
myArray1[]={2,3,4},
myArray2[]={1,2,3},
myArray3[]={1,2,4},
myArray4[]={1,3,4}.
```

firs element of myArray1 should be number from myArrays first element(1) to 4 but except 1 itself. So its gonna be {2,3,4}.
How can I create this arrays from myArray lets say every time I click button in Java (Android Studio)?

Comment: Add language please.

Comment: I am doing this in Android studio .

Comment: Just a reminder, user use `tag` to find interested question and then help you, please set correct `tag`, so more people could see your question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be a solution:

```
public static void main(String args[])
  {
    //Create myArray
    List<Integer> myArray= new ArrayList<>();
    myArray.add(4);
    myArray.add(5);
    myArray.add(6);
    myArray.add(7);

    //buttonClick
    List<List<Integer>> result = clickButton(myArray);

    //output all created Lists
    for(List<Integer> list : result){
      System.out.println("List: " + list);
    }
  }

  public static <T> List<List<T>> clickButton(List<T> myArray){
    //The List that will return. This Array contains all created Arrays
    List<List<T>> returnedArrays = new ArrayList<>();

    //For each element in myArray
    for(int i = 0; i < myArray.size(); i++) {

      //get the Element at position i (i increment each time)
      T object = myArray.get(i);

      //create a new Array
      List<T> array = new ArrayList<>();

      //add all elements from myArray to the new Array
      array.addAll(myArray);

      //remove the element by position i from the new Array
      array.remove(object);

      //add the new Array to the result Array
      returnedArrays.add(array);
    }
    //return the Array of all created Arrays
    return returnedArrays;
  }
```

You pass an array as parameter and become a List of all created Lists

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is too complex for me I am total beginner in this.

Comment: Insted of `T` you can write `Integer`. The T is only for generics. I add a description to my code

Answer (score 0):

A simple method that could achieve your goal could look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] myArray = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    // generate a sub array with element at index 0 left out
    int[] sub1 = subArray(myArray, 0);
    printArray(sub1);

    // generate all sub arrays of myArray in a cycle
    for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
        int[] sub2 = subArray(myArray, i);
        printArray(sub2);
    }
}

static int[] subArray(int[] arr, int removeInd){
    if(removeInd >= arr.length)
        return arr;        

    int[] newArray = new int[arr.length - 1];

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(i == removeInd)
            continue;
        newArray[i > removeInd ? i-1 : i] = arr[i];
    }
    return newArray;
}

static void printArray(int[] arr){
    for(int x : arr)
        System.out.print(x + " ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

The code now includes a complete example with usage.

The `subArray` method takes two parameters -- the original array and an index of the element that should not be included in the new array. If the index does not lie inside the original array, we just return the array back. Otherwise, we create a new array which is one element shorter than the original one and start copying the elements to the new array.

The indexing uses a ternary operator. Basically, before we reach the `removeInd` index, we copy all the elements to their original locations. After we skip the element to be removed, we need to decrement the original index of the elements by one (this way, we "patch" the hole in the array left by the removed element). This also ensures that we do not index outside the new array.

Example of the indexing in the call of `subArray({1, 2, 3, 4}, 1)`:

1. `i = 0`: `0 > 1` evaluates as false, therefore `newArray[0] = arr[0]`
2. `i = 1`: `i` is equal to `removeInd`, we dont copy anything
3. `i = 2`: `2 > 1` evaluates as true, therefore `newArray[1] = arr[2]` (see how we decrement the index in the new array but keep its value in the original one)
4. `i = 3`: `3 > 1` evaluates as true, therefore `newArray[2] = arr[3]`

Hopefully, this clarifies the inner workings of the code a little.

Comment: Thank you for answer! This is working only with myArray elements. When I change that numbers its not workng. Like myArray[] = {2,1,3,2}. Also what is newArray[i > removeInd ? i-1 : i] = myArray[i]; this means?

Comment: Answer edited, you can call the method with any integer array you like.

Answer (score 0):

A simple nested loop should do it. Not the most optimal approach if the lists get very big, but should be simple enough to understand what is happening. Basically, for each element in list we create a new list. And then we add all the other elements to the list.

```
public static List<List<Integer>> Action(List<Integer> intList){
       List<List<Integer>> listlistint = new ArrayList<>();
       for(int i = 0; i < intList.size(); i++){
            listlistint.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
           for(int j = 0; j < intList.size(); j++){
               if(i == j) continue;
               listlistint.get(i).add(intList.get(j));
           }
       }
       return listlistint;
     }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work. In the first line you forget to close the List with `>`, secondly the List type argument can't be a primitive type and to get the length of list the method call size() and not Length(). In the second loop you even forget the brackets by Length. If you show code, please look that the code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution for your problem with arrays instead of List:

```
public static void main(String args[])
  {
    int[] myArray = {4,5,6,7,8};

    int[][] result = clickButton(myArray);

    printArrays(result);
  }


  public static int[][] clickButton(int[] myArray){
    int[][] returnedArrays = new int[myArray.length][myArray.length -1];
    for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
      int[] array = new int[myArray.length - 1];
      for(int j = 0, k = 0; j < myArray.length; j++){
        if(j != i){
          array[k++] = myArray[j];
        }
      }
      returnedArrays[i] = array;
    }
    return returnedArrays;
  }


  public static void printArrays(int[][] arrayOfArrays){
    for(int[] list : arrayOfArrays){
      System.out.println("Array: ");
      for(int i : list)
        System.out.print(i);
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
```

Hope it solves your problem